# geographic sorting in e-commerce

Tags: user-expectation, users

We are building a complex website that sells products that require a teledoc experience before purchase. We have a segment of our audience that is national that will need to be funneled through another site to complete their order, whereas the local audience will be able to purchase directly on the existing site.

My questions is WHERE and WHEN to sort them. Should we make the geographical bifurcation clear on the home page, or wait until the user begins the purchase process? What would cause the least amount of friction?

Comment: can't the sorting be based on the IP address? Could you talk more about why you need to do the geographic bifurcation and how does it impact the user when they land on the homepage?

Comment: @harshikerfuffle nope, my ip address doesn't have to reflect my geographic location. For example I may be using the website from my office in Amsterdam but the traffic gets routed through our head office in Tokyo, I now have (for the outside world) a Japanese IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the users once they already started the purchase process causes less friction to the users who still have not taken a decision to buy, which are probably more numerous than the ones who already decided to buy.

On the other hand, some big e-commerce sites do this kind of sorting at the very beginning, probably to avoid showing wrong information to the users. I understand that it is easier to do the sorting clearly on the home page, but I prefer when it is done later, when the purchase process starts, because it feels more natural and less invasive.